# Custom HeaderView in listView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have 2 views for an item ListView. So one is used as HeaderView for ListView and the other in the other. That is the second marking takes the data from the   DetailsAdapter, which respectively are initialized fields.

```
public class DetailsAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<TicketObjects> {
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater  inflater;
private Context context;
public DetailsAdapter ( Context ctx, int resourceId, List<TicketObjects> objects) {
super( ctx, resourceId, objects );
resource = resourceId;
inflater = LayoutInflater.from( ctx );
context=ctx;
}
@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate( resource, null );
TicketObjects ticketObjects = getItem( position );

TextView depTransferCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTransferCity);
TextView detDepartTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartTime);
TextView detDepartDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartDate);
TextView detArriveTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveTime);
TextView detArriveDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveDate);
TextView depDepartCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.depDepartCity);
TextView detDepartAirport = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartAirport);
TextView detArriveCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveCity);
TextView detArriveAirport = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveAirport);
TextView detFlight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detFlight);
ImageView airlineLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detAirportLogo);

depTransferCity.setText(ticketObjects.getTransferCity());
detDepartTime.setText(ticketObjects.getDepartTime());
detDepartDate.setText(ticketObjects.getDepartDate());
detArriveTime.setText(ticketObjects.getArriveTime());
detArriveDate.setText(ticketObjects.getArriveDate());
depDepartCity.setText(ticketObjects.getDepartCity());
detDepartAirport.setText(ticketObjects.getDepartAirport());
detArriveCity.setText(ticketObjects.getArriveCity());
detArriveAirport.setText(ticketObjects.getArriveAirport());
detFlight.setText(ticketObjects.getFlight());
airlineLogo.setImageResource(ticketObjects.getAirlineLogo());

return convertView;
}
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lvDetails;
private Context ctx;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.ticket_details);
ctx=this;
List<TicketObjects> ticketObjectses = new ArrayList<>();
ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Бишкек", "Манас", "Ош", "Аэропорт Оша", "FRU", "13:45", "16.09.2015", "OSS", "13:45", "16.09.2015", "Almaty", "1ч 15мин", "15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));
ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Ош", "Аэропорт Оша", "Новосибирск", "Толмачево", "OSS", "15:43", "16.09.2015", "OVB", "17:45", "16.09.2015", "Astana", "1ч 25мин", "16000", R.drawable.logo_kazak, "Рейс: 543"));
ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Алматы", "Алматы", "Москва", "Домодедово","ALA","11:54","16.09.2015","DME","12:44","16.09.2015","Novosibirsk", "2ч 15мин","13000", R.drawable.logo_pegasus_logo, "Рейс: 543"));

lvDetails = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.lvDetails);

ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_header_item,lvDetails,false);

lvDetails.addHeaderView(header);
lvDetails.setAdapter(new DetailsAdapter(ctx, R.layout.ticket_details_item, ticketObjectses));
}
}
```

**ticket_details_item_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding"
android:layout_below="@+id/line"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:background="@drawable/layouts_border">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/leftPadding"
    android:background="#e8e8e8"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Бишкек"
        android:id="@+id/detTitleArriveCity"
        android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Нью-Йорк"
        android:id="@+id/detTitleArriveCity"
        android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_depart"
        android:padding="@dimen/rightPadding"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="35ч 00м"
        android:id="@+id/detTotalDuration"
        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/from"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/punktir"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/to"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="09:50"
            android:id="@+id/detDepartTime"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12.06.2016"
            android:id="@+id/detDepartDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartTime"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="11:40"
            android:id="@+id/detArriveTime"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartDate"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="13.06.2016"
            android:id="@+id/detArriveDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detArriveTime"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Бишкек"
            android:id="@+id/depDepartCity"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Манас"
            android:id="@+id/detDepartAirport"
            android:layout_below="@+id/depDepartCity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Москва"
            android:id="@+id/detArriveCity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartAirport"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Шереметьево"
            android:id="@+id/detArriveAirport"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detArriveCity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/stndHeight"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Рейс: AN565"
        android:id="@+id/detFlight"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detAirportLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_flyduba"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ticket_details_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/leftPadding"
    android:background="#e8e8e8"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
        android:id="@+id/locIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/location"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/leftPadding" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Пересадка:"
        android:id="@+id/textviewTransfer"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvTransferCity"
        android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:id="@+id/centerlayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/from"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/punktir"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/to"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="09:50"
            android:id="@+id/detDepartTime"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12.06.2016"
            android:id="@+id/detDepartDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartTime"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="11:40"
            android:id="@+id/detArriveTime"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartDate"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="13.06.2016"
            android:id="@+id/detArriveDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detArriveTime"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Бишкек"
            android:id="@+id/depDepartCity"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Манас"
            android:id="@+id/detDepartAirport"
            android:layout_below="@+id/depDepartCity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Москва"
            android:id="@+id/detArriveCity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartAirport"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Шереметьево"
            android:id="@+id/detArriveAirport"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detArriveCity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/stndHeight"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Рейс: AN565"
        android:id="@+id/detFlight"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detAirportLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_flyduba"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now ticket_details_header_item.xml nothing displays, that is, there are no data. A second view As you can see in the adapter is initialized and it has data.

**DetailObjects**

```
package kz.ticketdetail;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TicketObjects {

private String departCity;
private String departAirport;
private String arriveCity;
private String arriveAirport;

private String departCode;
private String departTime;
private String departDate;
private String arriveCode;
private String arriveTime;
private String arriveDate;
private String transferCity;
private String flyDuration;
private String ticketPrice;
private int airlineLogo;
private String flight;

public TicketObjects(String departCity, String departAirport, String arriveCity, String arriveAirport,
                     String departCode, String departTime, String departDate,
                     String arriveCode, String arriveTime, String arriveDate,
                     String transferCity, String flyDuration, String ticketPrice, int airlineLogo, String flight) {


    this.departCity = departCity;
    this.departAirport = departAirport;
    this.arriveCity = arriveCity;
    this.arriveAirport = arriveAirport;

    this.departCode = departCode;
    this.departTime = departTime;
    this.departDate = departDate;
    this.arriveCode = arriveCode;
    this.arriveTime = arriveTime;
    this.arriveDate = arriveDate;
    this.transferCity = transferCity;
    this.flyDuration = flyDuration.trim().replaceFirst("^[0]{1}", "").replace(":", " h ") + " m";
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
    this.airlineLogo = airlineLogo;
    this.flight = flight;
}


public static String getFormattingPrice(final String ticketPrice) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
    return formatter.format(Float.parseFloat(ticketPrice)).replace(",", " ");
}

public String getDepartCity(){
    return departCity;
}

public void setDepartCity(String departCity){
    this.departCity = departCity;
}

public String getDepartAirport(){
    return departAirport;
}

public void setDepartAirport(String departAirport){
    this.departAirport = departAirport;
}

public String getArriveCity(){
    return arriveCity;
}

public void setArriveCity(String arriveCity){
    this.arriveCity = arriveCity;
}

public String getArriveAirport(){
    return arriveAirport;
}

public void setArriveAirport(String arriveAirport){
    this.arriveAirport = arriveAirport;
}

public String getFlight(){
    return flight;
}

public void setFlight(String flight){
    this.flight = flight;
}

public String getDepartCode(){
    return departCode;
}

public void setDepartCode(String departCode){
    this.departCode = departCode;
}

public String getDepartTime(){
    return departTime;
}

public void setDepartTime(String departTime){
    this.departTime = departTime;
}

public String getDepartDate(){
    return departDate;
}

public void setDepartDate(String departDate){
    this.departDate = departDate;
}

public String getArriveCode(){
    return arriveCode;
}

public void setArriveCode(String arriveCode){
    this.arriveCode = arriveCode;
}

public String getArriveTime(){
    return arriveTime;
}

public void setArriveTime(String arriveTime){
    this.arriveTime = arriveTime;
}

public String getArriveDate(){
    return arriveDate;
}

public void setArriveDate(String arriveDate){
    this.arriveDate = arriveDate;
}

public String getTransferCity(){
    return transferCity;
}

public void setTransferCity(String transferCity){
    this.transferCity = transferCity;
}

public String getFlyDuration(){
    return flyDuration;
}

public void setFlyDuration(String flyDuration){
    this.flyDuration = flyDuration;
}

public String getTicketPrice(){
    return ticketPrice;
}

public void setTicketPrice(String ticketPrice){
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
}

public int getAirlineLogo(){
    return airlineLogo;
}

public void setAirlineLogo(int airlineLogo){
    this.airlineLogo = airlineLogo;
}

}
```

[image]

**Question:** How header view display the data from the array which MainActivity? Where should occur initialization ticket_details_header_item?

Comment: where you are setting data in list header?

Comment: In that case I do not know how to set Data(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the view from header and set data like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lvDetails;
private Context ctx;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.ticket_details);
ctx=this;
List<TicketObjects> ticketObjectses = new ArrayList<>();
ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Бишкек", "Манас", "Ош", "Аэропорт Оша", "FRU", "13:45", "16.09.2015", "OSS", "13:45", "16.09.2015", "Almaty", "1ч 15мин", "15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));
ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Ош", "Аэропорт Оша", "Новосибирск", "Толмачево", "OSS", "15:43", "16.09.2015", "OVB", "17:45", "16.09.2015", "Astana", "1ч 25мин", "16000", R.drawable.logo_kazak, "Рейс: 543"));
ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Алматы", "Алматы", "Москва", "Домодедово","ALA","11:54","16.09.2015","DME","12:44","16.09.2015","Novosibirsk", "2ч 15мин","13000", R.drawable.logo_pegasus_logo, "Рейс: 543"));

lvDetails = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.lvDetails);

View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_header_item,lvDetails,false);
TextView text1 = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.detTitleArriveCity);
TextView text2 = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.detTotalDuration);
// do the same far all your text views or what ever you want to get from layout.
TicketObjects mTicketObjects = ticketObjectses.get(0);
text1.setText(mTicketObjects.getDepartCity());
text2.setText(mTicketObjects.getFlyDuration());
// do the same for other options. 
lvDetails.addHeaderView(header);
lvDetails.setAdapter(new DetailsAdapter(ctx, R.layout.ticket_details_item, ticketObjectses));
}
}
```

do this for all items. inside the activity not in adapter. hope that answers your question.

Comment: Mustanser Iqbal, thank you verry much this helped but i dont know how to set data cause TextView arriveCity = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.detTitleArriveCity);
arriveCity.setText(ticketObjectses.getArriveCity); ticketObjectses.getArriveCity not working
Whats wrong?

Comment: check the answer i have updated the answer. you are trying to get header views in adapter. you need to get all views inside the activity.

Comment: Mustanser Iqbal, No i'm trying in activity! this TextView arriveCity = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.detTitleArriveCity);
arriveCity.setText("My text"); -- working. but when i try to call ticketObjectes - not working...

Comment: no, i'm trying set arriveCity.setText("Your data"); in MainActivity and data should be taken from the object ticketObjectes

Comment: it means your header is also the part of your listview. because ticket object data will vary as you scroll the list. and one more thing is your header is sticky header or it will scroll with list scroll.

Comment: how to get data should be taken from the object in ticketObjectes?

Comment: first clear me one thing that is you header is sticky or scrolling with list view?

Comment: scrolling with listview!

Comment: okay... now keep in mind that you wont be able to see the header data as scroll up. and goes outside the screen. if you only want to show data in header from very first ticket object then let me know i'll update the answer. if you want something else then please explain.

Comment: Yes, I only want to show data in header from very first ticket object

Comment: please share your ticket object class so i could add more specific answer. or just get the item from ticketObjectses list and show data in header as i have suggested. you can get item from ticketObjectses like this ticketObjectses.get(0).getDepartTime(). etc etc

Comment: Mustanser Iqbal, Updated!

Comment: you added the adapter i need this class TicketObjects. adapter is already in question